# on screen keyboard without function keys

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I am using osk.exe to get some information via

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe")
```

Is there any possibility that i could hide the function keys of that keyboard?
I only needed to show alpha and numeric keys

Comment: Do you need to hide them or just disable them? http://sleepydesign.blogspot.dk/2013/07/c-disable-system-keys-on-windows-on.html

Comment: Hide them. the sample you mentioned didn't  work